# Is '' base64 encoded?

Tags: javascript, regex, encoding, base64

Is '' base64 encoded?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860392/determine-if-string-is-in-base64-using-javascript/35002237) has this answer which suggests no:

```
if (str ==='' || str.trim() ===''){ return false; }
```

But some of the other approaches that use regular expressions return true ... For example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-xjubhf

Thoughts?

Comment: The base 64 encoding of an empty input is an empty string.

Comment: Makes sense ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

An empty string is encoded (and so decoded) as an empty string in BASE64.

Note: The exact first reference test in the BASE64 standard is the empty string:

> BASE64("") = ""

from [RFC 4648](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4648#section-10).